# Why can't I append a dictionary index for one item but I can for any other item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, ipfs

```
# Import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import ast

start_time = time.time()
s = requests.Session()

#Get URL and extract content
page=1
traits = []
accessories, backgrounds, shoes = [], [], []

while page != 100:

    params = {
        ('arg', f"Qmer3VzaeFhb7c5uiwuHJbRuVCaUu72DcnSoUKb1EvnB2x/{page}"),
    }

    content = s.get('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/cat', params=params, auth=('', ''))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    page = page + 1
    
    traits = ast.literal_eval(soup.text)['attributes']

    df = pd.DataFrame(traits)
    df1 = df[df['trait_type']=='ACCESSORIES']

    accessories.append(df1['value'].values[0])
```

Can anyone explain to my what I'm doing wrong? When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

But whenever I use a different index like BACKGROUNDS or SHOES instead of ACCESSORIES, like the following code, I don't get the above error and it runs perfectly.

```
# Import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import ast

start_time = time.time()
s = requests.Session()

#Get URL and extract content
page=1
traits = []
accessories, backgrounds, shoes = [], [], []

while page != 100:

    params = {
        ('arg', f"Qmer3VzaeFhb7c5uiwuHJbRuVCaUu72DcnSoUKb1EvnB2x/{page}"),
    }

    content = s.get('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/cat', params=params, auth=('', ''))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    page = page + 1
    
    traits = ast.literal_eval(soup.text)['attributes']

    df = pd.DataFrame(traits)
    df1 = df[df['trait_type']=='BACKGROUND']

    backgrounds.append(df1['value'].values[0])
```

Can anyone here help me figure out what I'm doing different or wrong between the two code?

P.S. When running either code up until the append line, both BACKGROUND and ACCESSORIES are listed in df and df1. Only when I add the append line does the ACCESSORIES index dissapear, but this doesn't happen for BACKGROUND or SHOES.

Comment: In your own words, what does `df1['value'].values[0]` mean? In your own words, what do you think should happen if `df1['value'].values` is empty? Did you *try to check* whether that is the case? Do you see why your choice of index might affect whether `df1['value'].values` is empty or not?

Comment: Do you think I am correct that that's where the problem is? If not, why not? If you didn't think about it, why not? Do you see anything in the error message that suggests where the problem is? Why not show the [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message?

Comment: Does this API request correspond to a web page that you can look at yourself? If it does, and you look at that web page, do you see any accessories listed? Do you see shoes and backgrounds listed?

Comment: thanks @KarlKnechtel I figured it out

Comment: @KarlKnechtel hey how would I go about filling in those empty values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code solves the issue:

```
# Import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import ast

start_time = time.time()
s = requests.Session()

#Get URL and extract content
page=1
traits = []
accessories, backgrounds, shoes = [], [], []

while page != 100:

    params = {
        ('arg', f"Qmer3VzaeFhb7c5uiwuHJbRuVCaUu72DcnSoUKb1EvnB2x/{page}"),
    }

    content = s.get('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/cat', params=params, auth=('', ''))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    page = page + 1
    
    traits = ast.literal_eval(soup.text)['attributes']

    df = pd.DataFrame(traits)
    df1 = df[df['trait_type']=='ACCESSORIES']

    try:
        accessories.append(df1['value'].values[0])
    except:
        pass
```